# How to preserve arc linetype when exporting from .dwg to ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, export, autocad, interoperability

I have a closed polyline in a .dwg that I need to export to a feature class as a polygon.

The polyline is composed of straight segments as well as arcs.

The arcs, however, get converted to many short, straight line segments when exported to shapefile.

It is required that the arc line type be preserved.

How can this be done?

I am using/have access to AutoCADMap3d, ArcGIS 10.2.2, and FME Desktop 2014 tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shapefile format does not support true curves ([one of many references here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000000w000000)). If you want to preserve a true curve, you must store it in a different format, such as a feature class in a geodatabase.

Comment: And then drop the curve to linear segments using the advanced edit tools *Generalize Line*, supply a maximum offset from the original curve, then you can make it into a shape file as it's been converted into a string of line segments.

Comment: Thank you. I was exporting FROM AutoCAD instead of importing TO ArcGIS. The latter method allows for the creation of gdb feature class, which supports curves.